# Validate String against Xml Schema Datatype in Java

Tags: java, xml, validation, types, schema

Is there a standard way to validate a string against any of the standard xml schema datatypes (see [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) or more specifically [Built-in-datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes))?

I don't want to validate a complete XSD, I just wand to validate some user input against XML datatypes (e.g. against http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date or http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean). Is there a way to do it using standard APIs? If not, are there other possibilitie instead of writing it from scratch?

The classes in the package javax.xml.validation seem to be targeted at validating complete schemas instead of specific datatypes.

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
String content = "abc";
String datatype = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#long";
boolean isValid = Validator.isValid(content, datatype); //return false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a standard API, but Xerces has an [XML Scheam API](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/index.html) that might be of interest. In Xerces you can also find data type validators that enables you to do  this:

```
import org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.InvalidDatatypeValueException;
import org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.YearDV;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
        new YearDV().getActualValue("Notayear", null);
        System.out.println("OK");
    } catch (InvalidDatatypeValueException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

which would print

```
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'Notayear' is not a valid value for 'gYear'.
```

Take it from there. Lots of code to read!

Comment: Looks good, but for performance reasons, I would prefer a solution that is not based on throwing and catching exceptions. However, if no other solution is suggested, I will accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
public boolean validate(String inputXml, String schemaLocation)throws SaxException, throws IOException {
// build the schema
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
File schemaFile = new File(schemaLocation);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

// create a source from a string
Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXml));

// check input
boolean isValid = true;
try {
validator.validate(source);
} catch (SaxException e) {
System.err.printlin("Not valid");
isValid = false;
}

return isValid;
}
```

Comment: The input that I want to validate is not XML and I do not have an actual schema. I just want to validate the datatype of a string, whereby the datatype is a standard Xml schema datatype (not an XML schema!).

Comment: what do you mean by standard Xml schema datatype??

Comment: The built-in-datatypes mentioned in "XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition". See [http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes).